# Display Text from DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, html.dropdownlistfor

Here's the view:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<TravelDeskWebsite.Models.TestModel>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>TestPage</title>
</head>
<body>
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   { %>
    <%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedText, ViewBag.Tests as SelectList)%>
    <%: (string)ViewBag.Test %>
<% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

The controller:

```
public ActionResult TestFunc(TestModel model)
    {

        List<string> TestList = new List<string>();
        TestList.Add("Help");
        TestList.Add("Please");
        ViewBag.Tests = new SelectList(TestList, model.SelectedText);
        ViewBag.Test = model.SelectedText;
        return View();
    }
```

What I wanted to achieve here is just to display the selected value as text on the same view.  The problem is that the ViewBag returns null even if I have a selected value.  When I test it, it throws null exception.

Comment: ViewBag is an MVC3 construct. If this is MVC2 it should be ViewData.

Comment: I'm using MVC3, updated above code with ViewBags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have your SelectedValue in the `SelectedText` Property. try to use that.

```
ViewBag.Test = model.SelectedText;
return View(model);
```

Comment: did u debug using breakpoints to see whether you are setting the correct value in your action method. ?

Comment: I do not know how to use breakpoints. Is there any other way that I could display the text even if I had to display it to another view?

Comment: Note to self: Always return view with the model as parameter if there are values bound to it.